# Document set link stub - page cannot be found error

Tags: document-set, hyperlink, records-management, records-center

After successfully sending a Document Set to the record centre, I click on the link stub which is left behind and instead of taking me to the new location of the document set, Sharepoint shows me a lovely page cannot be found error.

The Document Set can be successfully accessed in the record centre. The link stub is the only issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this or is it a limitation with Sharepoint and Document Sets?

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this Stack Overflow article on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955176/sharepoint-document-library-404-error), I have to ask:  has anyone changed the views of the Document Center lately?  That link giving the error could be pointing to an invalid view.